# Lynx cookies not being saved

Tags: lynx

If I'm not wrong, Lynx will save the cookies from a session on a file, the default is `~/.lynx_cookies`. But, when I accept cookies in Lynx session with `Always` or `Yes` when prompted, the cookies doesn't saved!

Lynx man page says:

> -cookie_file=FILENAME
> specifies a file to use to read cookies.  If none is specified, the default value is ~/.lynx_cookies for most systems, but ~/cookies for MS-DOS.
> -cookie_save_file=FILENAME
> specifies a file to use to store cookies.  If none is specified, the value given by -cookie_file is used.

But I don't have such file on my home directory.

What should I do to enable cookies on Lynx?

EDIT:
Thanks @stoney! It works!
What I have done:

```bash
$ cp /etc/lynx.cfg $HOME
$ export LYNX_CFG=$HOME/lynx.cfg
```

Add/edit this line on `$HOME/lynx.cfg`

```bash
SET_COOKIES:TRUE
PERSISTENT_COOKIES:TRUE
COOKIE_FILE:~/.lynx_cookies
COOKIE_SAVE_FILE:~/.lynx_cookies
```

Restart your terminal (or just source your `.bashrc`). Then, restart `lynx`. Done!

Comment: I removed "[SOLVED]" from the title. It is evident from the fact that you have accepted an answer that the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look for the config-directive `PERSISTENT_COOKIES`, this is what you're searching for. It's configured in `lynx.cfg`, usually in `/etc/lynx/`. You can use environment-variable `LYNX_CFG` to switch to another config.

This setting is more or less the opposite of "Discard Cookies at session-end" in desktop-browsers.